# How to get more information to auth variable in Rules with Email & Password authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

according to [this article](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/password.html), auth variable in Rules only gets uid and provider properties, while the client side authData gets password.email.
What if I want to write the rules base on the domain name in the email address? I would very much like to have password.email on the server side as well.

Or is there another way?

### Update (from comments)

Please consider the following code written by somebody who wants to gain access to any data that belongs to 'hotmail.com':

1. Create account `fbase.createUser({ email : 'john@example.com', password : 'qwerty' });`
2. Then he logs in and stores in Firebase `'/users/'+authData.uid+'/domain'` value `'hotmail.com'`

Does that not give him access to `'hotmail.com'` data even if his email in at example.com domain?

Comment: Sure. Store whatever value you have (in the client) in Firebase and check for the correct value in your security rules. E.g. `".write": "root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/domain).val() == 'hotmail.com'"`

Comment: Thanks for your response Frank van Puffelen. Please consider the following code written by somebody who want's to gain access to any data that belongs to 'hotmail.com': 1) Create account fbase.createUser({
    email    : 'john@example.com',
    password : 'qwerty'
  });
Then he logs in and stores in Firebase '/users/'+authData.uid+'/domain' value 'hotmail.com'

Does that not give him access to 'hotmail.com' data even if his email in at example.com domain?

Comment: That would indeed give john access to hotmail.com email, which is why you should write security rules that prevent them from doing this. You can either run an administrative task that sets the domains and is the only one with write access, or (more likely) you will make the domain a write-once setting and set it immediately when you create the user's settings. Regardless: you can/should probably validation rules that ensure that john stays in the example.com domain, but I have little experience with those.

Comment: Actually as I think about it, since the Email&Password authentication does not require email confirmation, john could as easily register himself as john@hotmail.com, and even if we did have Rules to enforce it, he would have access.

Comment: That is correct. I get the feeling you're trying to use Firebase's user identification mechanism to partition users. You might consider an alternative, such as an administrator associating each user with one or more domains. Or even simply setting up a separate Firebase for each domain, which makes them completely unable to see eachother's data, without you having to write security rules for it.

Comment: Setting up a separate Firebase was my first thought. Searching I found an answer here at StackOverflow, that there is no API to create Firebase. The goal here is, when a company purchases our service, their 'domain'/bucket/firebase is created and from then on only users with emails from that domain can register/use. The answer at StackOverflow was to have one Firebase and multiple children at root, one for each client. EDIT: This should all be unattended from our side.

Comment: You might want to reach out to support@firebase.com to see if anything has changed on that automatic creation of Firebases. Alternatively: I would simply add a `users` node under every sub-root, add your users there and grant access based on that. I've done that for a task board and it works fine. For me adding the users to a board is a administrator task, but you could definitely also automate that with a script that runs under an elevated user account (or your Firebase's secret token).

Comment: I requested it as a new feature. They contacted me, saying that it's in the works. Thanks for all your answers Frank van Puffelen!

Comment: OK. So you're good to go for now? In that case I'll vote to close this question.

Comment: Unless you can come up with a good answer, that might be useful to future visitors. In that case I'll retract my vote.